# Existing condition into JAVA 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can i convert the below condition to Java 8 streams way ?

```
    List<String> name = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    String id;
    if(name.contains("A")){
        id = "123";
    }else if(name.contains("B")){
        id = "234";
    }else if(name.contains("C")){
        id = "345";
    }
```

I am in process of learning Streams and was wondering how i can convert this one. I tried with foreach, map, filter but it was not getting at it

Comment: I am in process of learning Streams and was wondering how i can convert this one. I tried with foreach, map, filter but it was not getting at it.

Comment: Your actual code isn't so obvious as to what the desired behavior is, as it doesn't simply map one value to another, it checks elements in list with a priority based on order of checks. It is bad code in my opinion, it should be implamented as a method with multiple return statements instead of "else if" chain

Comment: The whole context here is converting the code to Streams. Not about the structure/syntax of the given code.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another (but compact) solution:

```
Arrays.asList("B", "C", "A", "D").stream()
        .map(s -> s.equals("A") ? new SimpleEntry<>(1, "123")
                : s.equals("B") ? new SimpleEntry<>(2, "234")
                : s.equals("C") ? new SimpleEntry<>(3, "345")
                : null)
        .filter(x -> x != null)
        .reduce((a, b) -> a.getKey() < b.getKey() ? a : b)
        .map(Entry::getValue)
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see why do you have to convert it to stream. This doesn't seem to be stream API case for me.
But if you want to easily add new items and make code more readable, I can suggest you to use map instead.

```
private static final ImmutableMap<String, String> nameToId = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String>()
    .put("A", "123")
    .put("B", "234")
    .put("C", "345")
    .build();
```

Now you can add new items without changing much code and just call `nameToId.get(name)` to fetch id by name.

You can add more flexibility here using streams

```
Stream.of("A", "B", "C").map(nameToId::get)collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: but what is missing somehow: where is your id for the list `("A", "B", "C")`? and what would it be for `("C", "A", "B")`?

Comment: @Roland In this case you will receive `null`s. But you can do whatever operations you need with the stream. For example you can `filter(Objects::notNull)` to remove nulls from the result. In case you want to replace nulls with default value you can do something like this `map(id -> id == null ? "default" : id)`

Comment: I don't get it. Why should I get `null`? What I want to know: which operation do you apply to get the id as in the example in the question? maybe I am just not seeing it.

Comment: This one: `map(nameToId::get)`

Comment: well... that would not return the id from the question but rather all matching ids...

Answer (score 2):

The problem you describe is to get a single value (id) from application of a function to two input sets: the input values and the mappings.

```
id = f(list,mappings)
```

So basically your question is, to find a *f* that is based on streams (in other words, solutions that return a list don't solve your problem).

First of all, the original if-else-if-else construct mixes three concerns:

- input validation (only considering the value set "A","B","C")
- mapping an input value to an output value ("A" -> "123", "B" -> "234", "C" -> "345")
- defining an implicit prioritization of input values according to their natural order (not sure if that is intentional or conincidental), "A" before "B" before "C"

When you want to apply this to a stream of input value, you have to make all of them explicit:

- a Filter function, that ignores all input value without a mapping
- a Mapper function, that maps the input to the id
- a Reduce function (BinaryOperator) the performs the prioritization logic implied by the if-else-if-else construct

### Mapping Function

The mapper is a *discrete* function mapping the input values to a one-element-stream of outputput values:

```
Function<String,Optional<String>> idMapper = s -> {
        if("A".equals(s)){
            return Optional.of("123");
        } else if("B".equals(s)){
            return Optional.of("234");
        } else if("C".equals(s)){
            return Optional.of("345");
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    } ;
```

For more mappings an immutable map should be used:

```
Map<String,String> mapping = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String,String>(){{
        put("A", "123");
        put("B", "234");
        put("C", "345");
    }}); //the instance initializer is just one way to initialize the map :)

Function<String,Optional<String>> idMapper = s -> Optional.ofNullable(mapping.get(s));
```

### Filter Function

As we only allow input values for which we have a mapping, we could use the keyset of the mapping map:

```
Predicate<String> filter = s -> mapping.containsKey(s);
```

### Reduce Function

For find the top-priority element of the stream using their natural order, use this BinaryOperator:

```
BinaryOperator<String> prioritizer = (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b) < 0 ? a : b;
```

If there is another logic to prioritize, you have to adapt the implementation accordingly.

This operator is used in a `.reduce()` call. If you prioritize based on natural order, you could use `.min(Comparator.naturalOrder())` on the stream instead.

Because the natur

### Stream Pipeline

Now you first have to reduce the stream to a single value, using the prioritizer, the result is an Optional which you flatMap by applying the idMapper function (flatMap to not end with Optional>

```
Optional<String> id = Arrays.asList("C", "B", "A")
                            .stream()
                            .filter(filter) //concern: input validation
                            .reduce(prioritizer) //concern: prioritization
                            .flatMap(idMapper); //concern: id-mapping
```

### Final Result

To wrap it up, for your particular problem, the most concise version (without defining functions first) using a stream and input validation would be:

```
//define the mapping in an immutable map (that's just one way to do it)
final Map<String,String> mapping = Collections.unmodifiableMap(
  new HashMap<String,String>(){{
      put("A", "123");
      put("B", "234");
      put("C", "345");
  }});

Optional<String> result = Arrays.asList("C", "D", "A", "B")
                                .stream()
                                .filter(mapping::containsKey) 
                                .min(Comparator.naturalOrder()) 
                                .flatMap(s -> Optional.ofNullable(mapping.get(s)));
```

which is the sought-for *f*:

```
BiFunction<List<String>,Map<String,String>,Optional<String>> f = 
   (list,map) -> list.stream()
                     .filter(map::containsKey) 
                     .min(Comparator.naturalOrder()) 
                     .flatMap(s -> Optional.ofNullable(mapping.get(s)));
```

There is certainly some appeal to this approach, but the elegance-through-simplicity of the if-else approach cannot be denied either ;)

But for the sake of completeness, let's look at complexity. Assuming the number of mappings and the number of input values is rather large (otherwise it wouldn't really matter).

Solutions based on iterating over the map and searching using contains (as in your if-else construct):

- Best-Case: o(1) (first branch in the if-else construct, first item in list)
- Worst-Case: O(n^2) (last branch in the if-else construct, last item in list)

For the streaming solution with reduce, you have to iterate completely through the input list (O(n)) while the map lookup is O(1)

- Best-Case: o(n)
- Worst-Case: O(n)

Thx to Hamlezz for the reduce idea and Holger for pointing out that applying the mapper function directly to the stream does not yield the same result (as first match wins and not the first entry in the if-else construct) and the min(Comparator.naturalOrder()) option.

Comment: ah got it, if-else defines a priority for A before B before C, while findFirst finds the first occurrence of any of A,B,C

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Serghey Bishyr's answer to use a map I also used a map (but ordered) and I will rather go through the keys of the map instead of the list to find the appropriate id. That might of course not be the best solution, but you can play with `Stream`s that way ;-)

```
Map<String, String> nameToId = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// the following order reflects the order of your conditions! (if your first condition would contain "B", you would move "B" at the first position)
nameToId.put("A", "123");
nameToId.put("B", "234");
nameToId.put("C", "345");

List<String> name = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
String id = nameToId.keySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(name::contains)
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(nameToId::get)
                    .orElse(null)
```

You gain nothing really... don't try to put too much into the filtering predicates or mapping functions, because then your `Stream` solution might not be that readable anymore.

Comment: This doesn’t do the same as the original code. Just try it with `Arrays.asList( "C", "B", "A")`…

Comment: Now it’s relying on `ImmutableMap` retaining the order. I don’t know whether there is such a guaranty.

Comment: I really appreciate and like your comments :-)